# Is it permissible to omit "is" in the following case?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> Denial. One of the strongest, most stubborn human feelings. It has nothing to
>   do with logic; its function **(is)** to prevent us from completely falling
>   apart, going insane.

Can I omit *is* in the example above?

Comment: In fact, what should be there is *being,* not *is,* it seems.

Comment: The excerpt already omits an "is" (between "Denial" and "One") by the simple expedient of cutting the idea "Denial is one of the strongest, most stubborn human feelings" into two pieces, neither of which has a visible verb. Given that start, you might establish a more even tone by removing all visible verbs. For example: "Denial. One of the strongest, most stubborn human feelings. Not as a matter of logic, but as a preventive measure against insanity."

Comment: @Kris: If there were a comma then *being* would make sense. With the semicolon (or with a period), *is* makes sense here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might appear to be possible to omit the **is** because there already is an implied **is** in the *it's function*. But this is a spelling mistake. It should be *its function*.

So, *its function* is the subject of the clause, which needs a verb (in this case the copula **is**) as the essential part of the predicate or complement.

You also need the *-ing* form of the last two verbs:

> Its function is to prevent us from completely *falling* apart, *going* insane.

Comment: This may be a side-effect of editing, but your answer now appears to contradict itself, by saying the correct spelling of "its function" is "its function".

Comment: @Dave. Thanks; I have restored the apostrophe which had indeed been removed by an editor.

Answer (score 4):

If *is* were missing from the position shown, the sentence would be badly formed.  The phrase before the semi-colon is an independent clause with subject and verb; for parallelism, an independent clause should follow the semicolon.

You might consider the following wordings.

> It has nothing to do with logic; it functions to prevent us falling completely apart...
>
> It's nothing to do with logic; it prevents us falling completely apart...

Answer (score 1):

No. A semicolon may only separate two independent clauses, and "is" provides the verb for the second clause. But since your apparent style in this context is pretty loose with the structure of a sentence: "Denial. One of the strongest and most stubborn human feelings." Perhaps keeping with that style would prove more effective:

Denial. One of the strongest, most stubborn human feelings. It has nothing to do with logic. Its function: to prevent us from completely falling apart. Going insane.
(I wouldn't do it for one's English teacher, however.)

I'm wondering,too, if a human feeling can be stubborn, or if *denial* is best described as a *feeling*.